# Notepad++ Find/Replace number with Increment Value

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible in Notepad++ to find a number, then replace it with increment value?

For example,
find id number: **regex `\((\d+)`**

```
INSERT INTO `wp_make`(`id`, `name`, `slug`) VALUES (0,"audi","audi");
INSERT INTO `wp_make`(`id`, `name`, `slug`) VALUES (1,"BMW","bmw");
INSERT INTO `wp_make`(`id`, `name`, `slug`) VALUES (2,"Mercedes","mercedes");
```

replace with id + 31: **how to?**

```
INSERT INTO `wp_make`(`id`, `name`, `slug`) VALUES (31,"audi","audi");
INSERT INTO `wp_make`(`id`, `name`, `slug`) VALUES (32,"BMW","bmw");
INSERT INTO `wp_make`(`id`, `name`, `slug`) VALUES (33,"Mercedes","mercedes");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible with just a regex, but you can use a python script inside Notepad++.

Here are the steps:

- Install [Python Script 1.0.8.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%201.0.8.0/)
- Go to the *Plugins* -> *Python Script* -> *New Script*
- Select the file name (say, "increment_numbers.py")
- Place this script there:

Code:

```
def increment_after_openparen(match):
    return "({0}".format(str(int(match.group(1))+31))

editor.rereplace(r'\((\d+)', increment_after_openparen)
```

Then, just evoke this 'increment_numbers' script.

Answer (score 1):

*Addendum to the accepted answer. Posting this as an answer due to insufficient rep*

I noted that the newer version of Notepad ++ is not compatible with this python script. I installed notepad++ 6.6.9 and now the Python menu tab shows up under plugins.