# Notepad ++ How to multiply numbers from mass replace?

Tags: replace, notepad++

I'm trying to multiply value in

```
"StackSize" Value="x"
```

By 3.

So all Values in x would be three times bigger.
How can I do it by using mass replace?

Comment: Are those numeric values of float or integer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Notepad++ does not have the facilities to do arithmetic in its search/replace commands. Tasks like this can be done with programming or scripting languages. For example the Perl substitution `s/.../.../e` could be used

Quoting from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html:

> A /e will cause the replacement portion to be treated as a full-fledged Perl expression and evaluated right then and there

Notepad++ has plugins that provide good support for Python and that may allow you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in regex-based calculation feature of this kind in Notepad++, but you may leverage the Notepad++ PythonScript plug-in.

[Install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757) and use the following code in the script file:

```
def multiply_number_in_context(match):
    return "{0}{1}{2}".format(match.group(1), str(float(match.group(2))*3), '"')

editor.rereplace(r'("StackSize" Value=")(\d+)"', multiply_number_in_context)
```

If you plan to multiply integer values, replace `float(match.group(2))*3)` with `int(match.group(2))*3)`.