# I need help to round numbers for currency conversion in a text file using notepad++ and python script plugin

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

It would be nice is someone can help me.

I have text files that looks like this :

```
#Zsdfgsdqfq
#A100,56
#Zjtdhsdfg
#Zadsdf
#B12,53
#Zdwfgs
#C10,00
#Zdsfgdfg
#D40,00
```

In the file #A, #B, #C and D# are numbers that I need to divide by 6.55957
This is the result that I want :

```
#A15,33
#Zjtdhsdfg
#Zadsdf
#B1,91
#Zdwfgs
#C1,52
#Zdsfgdfg
#D6,10
```

I've found this helpful discussion : [Notepad ++ How to multiply numbers from mass replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648640/notepad-how-to-multiply-numbers-from-mass-replace)

So I used the Python script plugin in Notepad++

I can't figure how to manage decimal numbers and the comma used for decimal separator.

I've discovered I can delete all comas then divide the result by 100 and I will be able to search and replace to replace dots with comas in the resulting file.

Here is my script based on what I read on the linked discussion :

```
def multiply_number_in_context(match):
    return "{0}{1}".format(match.group(1), str(int(match.group(2))/655.957)) # thank you Wiktor Stribiżew to explain me how to get rid of this : ,''

editor.rereplace(r'(\#A)(\d+)', multiply_number_in_context)
editor.rereplace(r'(\#B)(\d+)', multiply_number_in_context)
editor.rereplace(r'(\#C)(\d+)', multiply_number_in_context)
editor.rereplace(r'(\#D)(\d+)', multiply_number_in_context)
```

Here is the result :

```
#Zsdfgsdqfq
#A15.33027317339399
#Zjtdhsdfg
#Zadsdf
#B1.910186185984752
#Zdwfgs
#C1.524490172374104
#Zdsfgdfg
#D6.097960689496415
```

It works but now I need to round the results with two decimals. #A should be 15.33 and #D should be 6.10

It seems the way is using the round(x, 2) thing but I can't figure ho to make this work.

I tried to modify my script with this sort of things this :

```
return "{0}{1}{2}".format(match.group(1), str(round(int(match.group(2))/655.957), '')), 2)
```

or to modify the script so it rounds the numbers instead of multiplying but with no success I have syntax errors and such.

It would be kind if someone can improve my script so it rounds the result or give me another script that will round my results.

I don't want to learn programing I'm just searching for a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following fixed script:

```
def multiply_number_in_context(match):
    return "{0:.2f}".format(float(match.group(0).replace(',', '.'))*100.0/655.957).replace(".",",")

editor.rereplace(r'(?<=#[A-Z])\d+(?:,\d+)?', multiply_number_in_context)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n5JVav/1). Details:

- `(?<=#[A-Z])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `#` and then any uppercase ASCII letter (change to `[A-D]` to only match `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)?` - an optional substring that matches

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

Results:

[image]

**Notes**

- `match.group(0).replace(',', '.')` replaces the comma with a dot to simplify calculations
- `float(...)*100.0/655.957` - the found number is cast to float, multiplied by 100 and divided by 655.957
- `"{0:.2f}".format(...)` - formats the float rounded result
- `.replace(".",",")` - reverts the decimal separator to `,`.

Comment: Thanks for your help that's perfect.
Can't I just use : "/6.55957 " instead of "*100.0/655.957" ?

Comment: @anthonyb You may do whatever your requirements are. I just did that because of your input values that I did not modify.