# replace after "word" character by character in notepad ++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a STRING

"wordride plain fire "

I have tried to replace with *Regular Expressions*:

- Find what: `(?>(word)|\G(?<!^))\K\S`
- Replace with: `$1$2$0`

In Notepad ++, it does not change the text but it works in regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/aI6gE1/2), where i replaces characters after `word` as follows

- First replace: `wordwordide plain fire`
- Second replace: `wordwordwordde plain fire`
- Third replace: `wordwordwordworde plain fire`
- Fourth replace: `wordwordwordwordword plain fire`
- Fifth replace: `wordwordwordwordwordwordplain fire`
- Sixth replace: `wordwordwordwordwordwordwordlain fire`

Can you help me to see the error or give me a workaround in Notepad ++ for this purpose: *replacing string after "word" character by character using a group not included in match group*

Please help me

Comment: What is the regular expression you are using? Please read [mcve] then [edit] the question to include the missing details.

Comment: Please add expected result after the replacement and add the regex as text.

Comment: Is the word known? If yes, [replace with some `::<>::`](https://regex101.com/r/wU1lX9/1) and then [replace this placeholder with the required word](https://regex101.com/r/xO2fJ0/1).

Comment: I really was looking for a solution like this but in reverse
. (? =. * (Word))                                         replace for this                                  $1

Comment: In reverse means you need an infinite width look**behind**, not look*ahead*. And it is not possible in Notepad++. Use Python PyPi regex module, or .NET, or VIM... Do you want exactly [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d(word).*).&i=wordride+plain+fire+&r=%241)? In VIM, I guess, it is something like `:%s/\(\(word\).*\)\@<=./\1/g`

Comment: thanks i just switched to csharp but i have a problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088949/because-this-code-dont-work-in-csharp

Comment: Why did you mark the answer below as accepted if it does not work for you? Try [`(?sm)(?<=^(work\d+).*?(?>\r\n|\r?\n))(\s*\S+)\s+[\t\p{Zs}]+(&[\d.]+)?` and replace with `$1$2 $3`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fsm)(%3f%3c%3d%5e(work%5cd%2b).*%3f(%3f%3e%5cr%5cn%7c%5cr%3f%5cn))(%5cs*%5cS%2b)%5cs%2b%5b%5ct%5cp%7bZs%7d%5d%2b(%26%5b%5cd.%5d%2b)%3f&i=work1%26title%0d%0a%0d%0avalue2%26ame2+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2623.04+%0d%0a%0d%0avalu4%26name4+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2681.36+%0d%0a%0d%0avalue1%26name1++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2681.36+&r=%241%242+%243).

Comment: ok thankyou , i accept your response

Comment: anyway, notepad ++ had many bugs,
so I switch to csharp
thank you for the advice

Comment: You should undelete the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088949/because-this-code-dont-work-in-csharp, or change the current question and re-tag it. I'd rather you keep this one open, and undelete the deleted question.

Comment: I have added an answer specific for Notepad++ and this current task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, it is possible to do with Notepad++ **BUT** only with the help of a PythonScript plug-in.

[Get the plugin ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757), and create the following script:

```
import re

regex = r"^(word)(.+)"

def process_match(match):
    return "{0}{1}".format(match.group(1), "".join([match.group(1) for x in list(match.group(2))]))
editor.rereplace(regex, process_match)
```

The `^(word)(.+)` pattern will match a line with `word` at its start into Group 1 and all the rest of the line into Group 2.

The `"{0}{1}".format(match.group(1), "".join([match.group(1) for x in list(match.group(2))]))` will paste the Group 1 value into the result first (see `format(match.group(1)`) and then `"".join([match.group(1) for x in list(match.group(2))])` will replace each character in Group 2 with the value in Group 1.

This text:

```
word1
word1 2
wordride plain fire
```

will turn into:

[image]

**NOTE**: You can control how many chars after `word` are replace with `word` by adjusting (modifying) the `(.+)` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what you want to do but the following is working based on your examples:

- Find: `^((word)+).`
- Replace with: `$1$2`

Comment: I do not think it is working at all. See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE8nR8/1): only the first char after `word` gets replaced with the word. IMHO, it is not possible to do with 1 regex replacement operation.

Comment: Then I really have not understood what he tries to do :)

Comment: I just switched to csharp