# replace after string character by character in (notepad ++) using a not matched group?

Tags: regex, string

i want replace after "string"

stringreplacefield
character by character

for generate

```
 stringstringeplacefield
```

after the first replace

```
  stringstringstringplacefield
```

after the second replace

```
 stringstringstringstringlacefield
```

after third replace

```
 stringstringstringstringstringacefield
```

using a not matched group
in notepad++

I have tried this several days

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

```regex
(((?:string)+)(?!string).([^\n\r]*?)(field))\Z
```

**Replace With:** `$1\n$2string$3$4`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## From Notepad ++

From Notepad++, note that you should be using notpad++ version 6.1 or later as there were problems with regular expressions in an older version that have been solved now.

1. press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to enter the find and replace
   mode
2. Select the Regular Expression option
3. In the "Find what" field enter `(((?:string)+)(?!string).([^\n\r]*?)(field))\Z`
4. in the "Replace with" field enter `$1\n$2string$3$4`
5. Click <kbd>Replace all</kbd>. Each time you click replace all, a new character will be eaten, and a new line will be inserted.

## Example

**Regex Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/jK6jF7/1

**Sample text**

```
stringreplacefield
```

**After Replacement**

```
1st time
   stringreplacefield
   stringstringeplacefield

2nd time
   stringreplacefield
   stringstringeplacefield
   stringstringstringplacefield

3rd time
   stringreplacefield
   stringstringeplacefield
   stringstringstringplacefield
   stringstringstringstringlacefield

4th time
   stringreplacefield
   stringstringeplacefield
   stringstringstringplacefield
   stringstringstringstringlacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringacefield

5th time
   stringreplacefield
   stringstringeplacefield
   stringstringstringplacefield
   stringstringstringstringlacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringcefield

6th time
   stringreplacefield
   stringstringeplacefield
   stringstringstringplacefield
   stringstringstringstringlacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringcefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringstringefield

7th time
   stringreplacefield
   stringstringeplacefield
   stringstringstringplacefield
   stringstringstringstringlacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringcefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringstringefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringstringstringfield

8th time since there are no more characters between "string" and field, then no more replacements are made
   stringreplacefield
   stringstringeplacefield
   stringstringstringplacefield
   stringstringstringstringlacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringacefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringcefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringstringefield
   stringstringstringstringstringstringstringstringfield
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        string                   'string'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )+                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      string                   'string'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\n\r]*?                any character except: '\n' (newline),
                               '\r' (carriage return) (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      field                    'field'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \Z                       before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: hi goog answer but i want this in one line not multiple lines and; not using "string" using a variable for replace charcater for string redirecting

Comment: please if possible see my other question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902418/replace-after-word-character-by-character-in-notepad                                      and resolve it

Comment: for example i see other example of you redirect a variable \s(?=.{18}(.))                                                        , i want use any character after string and replace by string as not matching group  using a subtitution $1

Comment: good answer, I think I have no problems I could solve my doubt thanks to your other answer, very thankyou