# Regex, how to remove Linefeeds in a pipe delimted file EXCEPT after the nth |?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a pipe delimited file with 35 pipes per line.There is an expected line feed after the 35th field. For example:

```
FirstField|ME|HERE|PHONE|Description|.....|LastField
FirstField|YOu|THERE|PHONE|Description|.....|LastField
```

However, some of the data between pipes (for example in a description field) contains line feeds. Eg:

```
FirstField|Them|Where|PHONE|This contains a
LineFeed
Or two
or more|.....|LastField
```

Question is, how to remove the Line Feeds in any of the 35 fields, but not at the end of the line?

(Off note: I'm working in Notepad++ for testing)

Comment: FirstField|Them|Where|PHONE|This contains <br>

 a
<br>
 LineFeed Or two or more|.....|LastField

Comment: Do you mean 34 pipes and 35 fields, or 35 pipes and 36 fields?

Comment: This isn't well suited for regex, I'd recommend writing a short Python script instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may leverage the Notepad++ PythonScript plug-in.

[See instructions on how to install a working version here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757) and create the following script file:

```
def repl(match):
    return match.group(0).replace("\r\n", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")

editor.rereplace(r'^[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*){36}$', repl)
```

If you name the script file as `replace_lbr_inblock.py`, you will be able to call it by selecting *Plugins* -> *Python Script* -> *Scripts* -> *replace_lbr_inblock*.

The regex `^[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*){36}$` matches

- `^` - start of the line
- `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than `|`
- `(?:\|[^|]*){36}` - 36 sequences of a `|` followed with zero or more pipes
- `$` - end of line.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: This can only break if there is a `|` inside your data, or the number of columns is not fixed (although it is mentioned the number of columns is fixed). Please let know if it is possible that `|` inside the data is possible (in an escaped form?).