# Using Notepad, can I remove spaces during a regex find and replace while using backtracking?

Tags: regex, notepad++, flat-file

I am using Notepad++ (version 6.9.2)

I have a fixed width flat file database that I need to re-arrange and cleanup.

Example of file:

```
0001168500Mel     Maenyey Legal College                                                                       91PO Box 867                                                                                          Lutghjhe                                          403003Jellisa Moneyey                                             07 3660 2551        07 3660 2211        Jellisa@gglegalcollege.com.nz
```

Here is my current 'find' regex:

```
^(.{10})(.{100})(.{2})(.{50})(.{50})(.{50})(.{4})(.{2})(.{60})(.{20})(.{20})(.{80})
```

and here is my 'replace' regex:

```
"$1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12"
```

These work well however I would like to:

1. not copy over the padding spaces (right or left)
2. Remove left '0' (zeros) from numerical values - none in this example file but there are some in other files.

I have searched and can't find examples of where this might be possible in the same regex. I could do another regex after but if there is something quick and easy to add to this one it would be nice ;-)

Comment: It's easier if you do it in multiple steps. After you've applied the regex you have and everything's neatly separated by commas, you can just replace `"[ 0]+| +"` with `"`

Comment: I think you can easily add these post-processing in a Python script. If you are interested, I will "cook" one when I have a spare minute.

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex yields this output:

```
"0001168500","Mel     Maenyey Legal College                                                                       ","91","PO Box 867                                        ","                                                  ","Lutghjhe                                          ","4030","03","Jellisa Moneyey                                             ","07 3660 2551        ","07 3660 2211        ","Jellisa@gglegalcollege.com.nz                                                   "
```

The problem with a regex approach is that you have fixed width fields, and the number of possible leading zeros and leading/trailing whitespaces is variable. Although in some cases it can be helped with possessive matching and lookbehinds, I'd recommend to use a more flexible, code based approach.

[Install the working PythonScript version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757), and create a script file with the following contents:

```
import re
def repl(match): 
    return '"{0}","{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}","{5}","{6}","{7}","{8}","{9}","{10}","{11}"'.format(
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(1).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(2).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(3).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(4).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(5).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(6).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(7).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(8).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(9).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(10).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(11).strip()),
        digit_reg.sub(r'\1', match.group(12).strip())
    )

pat = r'^(.{10})(.{100})(.{2})(.{50})(.{50})(.{50})(.{4})(.{2})(.{60})(.{20})(.{20})(.{80})'
digit_reg = re.compile(r'^0+([0-9]*)$')
editor.rereplace(pat, repl)
```

The pattern you have will be used to match separate fields. The match data object will be passed to the `repl` method, where each of the fields will be trimmed with `.strip()` method from the leading/trailing whitespaces, and the `^0+([0-9]*)$` regex will be applied to all the fields to remove leading zeros in strings that only consist of digits.

[image]