# Add certain number of line breaks in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try to add a given number of line breaks in Notepad++. But searching for `\r\n` and replacing with `[\r\n]{10}` doesn't work for me. Regular expressions interpretation is on.
How should i add a number of line breaks?

Comment: Use `Extended`mode and replace `\r\n` with  `\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n`

Answer (score 2):

Note that a replacement pattern is not accepting a regular expression. A regex can be used inside *Find what* field, but not in *Replace with*.

Use `Extended`mode and replace `\r\n` with  `\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n` to replace 1 linebreak with 10.

A regex to match any line break is `\R` (be it `\r\n`, or `\n` or `\r`), by the way.

To make it more "dynamic", you may use a PythonScript like

```
editor.rereplace(r'\r\n', '\r\n'*10)
```

Comment: and if it should be 100 or 1000? i'm looking for regex with specification of the number

Comment: It is impossible with regex replacement in SR window. You may write a Python script to accomplish that though. See my update. [See how to use PythonScript in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757).