# Format text file so that the id is constantly ascending by one

Tags: json, regex, text, format, notepad++

I have a json file that has this type of format:

**{"id":61,"statement":"English is the language spoken in the largest number of countries in the world.","correct":true,"additional":null},**

**{"id":62,"statement":"Italy is shaped like a hat.","correct":false,"additional":"Italy is shaped like a boot."},**

**{"id":63,"statement":"The Cape of Good Hope is in South Africa.","correct":true,"additional":null},**

**{"id":65,"statement":"The largest island in the world is Hawaii.","correct":false,"additional":"Greenland is the largest island in the world that isn't considered a continent."},**

It contains 6k rows of data and sometimes like in example id skips a number (63 - 65), I want to to start the first id with 1 and gradually increase by 1. How can it be achieved? I suppose regex could be of use here.

Comment: Write a Python script in NPP to fix that, or better just use Python staight.

Comment: That's a quite general comment

Comment: I don't have experience with python so I wouldn't know where to start :D

Comment: Well, it is never late to improve your skills. Here is [my previous answer that will give you a jumpstart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757). You will need a regex like `r'("id"\s*:\s*)(\d+)'` and then use 2 groups in the replacement callback method.