# notepad++, recalculate numbers with replace

Tags: replace, notepad++

I'm trying to recalculate numbers in a file and replace them with new values.
For example;

```
value=50
value=60
value=70
value=80
value=90
value=100
value=110
```

in file, I have some numbers and I want them divide by 2 and replace with new values.

I can find the numbers `(\d+)$` and I can't use math operators when replace like `$1 / 2` or `($1 / 2)`
How I can replace their values with math applied values?

after replacement done, values should look like that

```
value=25
value=30
value=35
value=40
value=45
value=50
value=55
```

Comment: You can't easily do this in Notepad++ using regex alone, AFAIK.  But, this would be easy to handle using a programming language.  Do you have any other options besides Notepad++?

Comment: You may do it in NPP using a PythonScript script. It is rather straightforward there since you are using Python then. Probably, using Python itself would make more sense. Or any other full-fledged language.

Comment: Hi Tim, I can do it easily in C# but, notepad++ functions and colors and readability is much more better. So, I am analyzing file first then replacing values. It is why I'm trying with notepad++

Comment: I vote for doing this in C# then.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I never seen a script can be usable in notepad++, I'll research for it. Thank you

Comment: You may see my previous related answers, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757) will surely help. Probably, we may even close this question as a dupe, there is everything you need to solve this current issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ Find/Replace number with Increment Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value)