# search and replace with regex to increment numbers in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, search, replace, visual-studio-code, increment

I'm currently working on a big svg sprite.
The diffrent images are always 2000px apart.

What I have is:

```
<g transform="translate(0,0)">
<g transform="translate(0,2000)">
<g transform="translate(0,4000)">
```

After regex want this so just adding 2000 onto the second number:

```
<g transform="translate(0,2000)">
<g transform="translate(0,4000)">
<g transform="translate(0,6000)">
```

I have the issue now that some new images have to be put at the top of the document, thus meaning i would need to change all numbers and they are quite alot.

I was thinking about using regular expressions and even found out that it works in the search bar of VS Code. The thing is i never worked with any regex and i'm kinda confused.

Could someone give me a solution and an explanation for incrementing all the sample numbers by 2000?
I hope i understand it afterwards so i can get my foot into that topic.
I'm also happy with just links to tutorials in general or my specific use case.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: No, you need a full fledged language here. Python, for example, can do that easily. If you wish it can also be done in Perl.

Comment: I had a now coworker once watching over my shoulder who did something like this in the search bar of vs code though.

But im speaking a bit python so if you like to share your knowledge i think it will be usefull to learn as well :)

Comment: Incrementing by just 1 is possible and probably a workaround for `2000` can also be written (it involves several regex replacements), but a generic way is to get all matches and use a replacement method as a replacement argument where you can manipulate the match before the replacement result gets back into the modified string.

Comment: Just in case, you may use Notepad++ with Python Script for incrementing any numbers in specified contexts, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ty very much this indeed seems useful how ever there is no explanation of the regular expression itself in the linked solution.
I understand the pyton part but the regex part is chinese for me.
Can u make an example for my use case or give me a tutorial how to read it?
Also are those regex unique to the language or are they universal for every language?

Comment: Because it is basic. Just a `(` and 1+ digits, there is nothing to explain. In your case, it is just not clear what numbers and in what context you want to change.

Comment: i edited my last comment i did submit it to early by accident

i dont know how to format in comment section so:
https://pastebin.com/jqP6vP4s

Comment: You need to use `(transform="translate\(\d+,\s*)(\d+)` regex and modify the function to `return "{0}{1}".format(match.group(1),str(int(match.group(2))+2000))`

Comment: Ok i tried, hope this is correct i never never used stuff like d+ s* etc. in python yet.
https://pastebin.com/WGhcd5Me

Comment: I do not have any `(` in my above comment. It must be `"{}{}"` or `"{0}{1}"`. The rest looks correct

Comment: It works i love you man!
But i guess i have to look through the documentation of re and some other stuff because i only got a vague idea of what i just did and that's not  how it should be.

Comment: This stuff is advanced, great it worked out :)

Comment: I think I should post an answer.

Comment: Yes i was just confused because i thought i could pick a comment as solution but apperently not :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VSCode, you can't replace with an incremented value inside a match/capture. You can only do that inside a callback function passed as the replacement argument to a regex replace function/method.

You may use Notepad++ to perform these replacements after installing Python Script plugin. [Follow these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300462/notepad-find-replace-number-with-increment-value/37300757#37300757) and then use the following Python code:

```
def increment_after_openparen(match):
    return "{0}{1}".format(match.group(1),str(int(match.group(2))+2000))

editor.rereplace(r'(transform="translate\(\d+,\s*)(\d+)', increment_after_openparen)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l9MBb4/2).

Note:

- `(transform="translate\(\d+,\s*)(\d+)` matches and captures into Group 1 `transform="translate(` + 1 or more digits, then `,` and 0 or more whitespaces (with `(transform="translate\(\d+,\s*))`) and then captures into Group 2 any one or more digits (with `(\d+)`)
- `match.group(1)` is the Group 1 contents, `match.group(2)` is the Group 2 contents.

Basically, any group is formed with a pair of unescaped parentheses and the group count starts with 1. So, if you use a pattern like `(Item:\s*)(\d+)([.;])`, you will need to use `return "{0}{1}{2}".format(match.group(1),str(int(match.group(2))+2000), match.group(3))`. Or, `return "{}{}{}".format(match.group(1),str(int(match.group(2))+2000), match.group(3))`.

Comment: Hoping VS Code updates this functionaliy. FWIW - TextPad has support OOTB for incrementing replacements using the `\i` replacement expression. No special functions to write - which may mean it is too simplistic in some scenarios. But it has worked great for me through the years.

Comment: @bkwdesign That's interesting, thanks for letting know. Surely, there are other proprietary tools that allow this kind of incrementing in a regex replacement, I also know Funduc Search and Replace tool that can do that.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an extension, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#review-details), to make these math operations on find and replaces with regex's quite simple (and much more like path variables, conditionals, string operations, etc.).  In this case, this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) will do what you want:

```
{
  "key": "alt+r",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    
    "find": "(?<=translate\\(\\d+,\\s*)(\\d+)",  // double-escaped
    
    "replace": "$${ return $1 + 2000 }$$",
    
    "isRegex": true,

    // "restrictFind": "document",  // or line/once/selections/etc. 
  }
}
```

That could also be a setting in your `settings.json` if you wanted that - see the README.

`(?<=translate\\(\\d+,\\s*)`  a positive lookbehind, you can use non-fixed length items in the lookbehind, like `\\d+`.

`(\\d+)` capture group 1

The replace: `$${ return $1 + 2000 }$$`

`$${ <your string or math operation here> }}$`

`return $1 + 2000` add 2000 to capture group 1

Demo:

[image: math operation on a find regex]

Answer (score 0):

SublimeText3 with the Text-Pastry add-in can also do \i

Answer (score 0):

you can use the extension I made: [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

- Select the numbers with Multi Cursor, can be done with Regex Find and `Alt+Enter` in find box
- Run command: **Generate text based on regular expression**
- As `Match Expression` use: `(\d+)`
- As generator extression use: `{{=N[1]+2000}}`
- You get a preview of the result.
- Press `Enter` if OK, or `Esc` to abort

You can set this type of search replace as a predefined in the setting `regexTextGen.predefined`

```
  "regexTextGen.predefined": {
    "Add/Subtract a number" : {
      "originalTextRegex": "(\d+)",
      "generatorRegex": "{{=N[1]+1}}"
    }
  }
```

You can edit the expressions (change the `1`) if you choose a predefined.